# Project a texture onto a Mesh from a Curve

Tags: texturing, uv, bezier-curves

I've been looking for an answer to this for a while now. I have a mesh object, where I would like to draw lines on it, *without* using the texture paint tool. For instance: a mesh garment with stitch or seam lines, defined by a NURBS or Bézier Curve. So far I've been able to put texture "Decals" on an object by using an Empty, but I've not been able to draw a "line" using an arbitrary Curve. Has anyone done this, or know if this is possible?

[image: Image explaining the above]

Comment: As far as I know there is no such workflow in Blender, maybe dynamic paint or baking can be used, but it will probably be an involved workflow.

Comment: Yes, currently I'm baking all the textures on. I tried adding a texture using the Object coordinates of the curve, but it only seems to take the origin of said curve; it doesn't take the length or the contour into consideration.